# How do I wait for properties like color changes in WPF?

Tags: testcomplete8

I want to check, whether a background that was grey turned into black.
Usually I wait for changes of attributes like this:

```
Aliases.MyApp.BtnCalculationType.WaitProperty("Enabled", "True", 9999999);
```

Unfortunately

```
Aliases.MyApp.BtnCalculationType.WaitProperty("Fill.Color.B", "0", 9999999);
```

does not work. What to do instead?

Comment: What exactly does "does not work" mean? Are you getting any error messages?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the [`Fill.Color.B`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.b.aspx) property value is a number, not a string, so you need to remove quotes around 0:

```js
Aliases.MyApp.BtnCalculationType.WaitProperty("Fill.Color.B", 0, 9999999)
```

Secondly, `Fill.Color.B` is the color's blue component. You may need to also check the red, green and alpha components. To do this, you need to use a custom comparison instead of `WaitProperty` (`WaitProperty` doesn't support checking multiple properties at once). For example:

```js
// JScript
var btn = Aliases.MyApp.BtnCalculationType;
while ((btn.Fill.Color.B != 0) || (btn.Fill.Color.R != 0) || (btn.Fill.Color.G != 0))
  Delay(500);
```